# When to use Poisson distribution?

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

I'm still very confused regarding when to use probability distributions.

For instance, this is the assumptions to use Poisson distribution, according to Wikipedia:

- k is the number of times an event occurs in an interval and k can take values 0, 1, 2, ...
- The occurrence of one event does not affect the probability that a second event will occur. That is, events occur independently.
- The average rate at which events occur is independent of any occurrences. For simplicity, this is usually assumed to be constant, but may in practice vary with time.
- Two events cannot occur at exactly the same instant; instead, at each very small sub-interval, either exactly one event occurs, or no event occurs.

Does that mean that I can assume that any event that follow this assumptions follow a Poisson distribution? If that is the case, why do so many books have exercises mentioning "assume that ... follow a Poisson distribution"? Isn't that unnecessary?

For instance: Let's say I work in a call-centre and I observe that I have 2 calls in the first hour, 3 in the second, 10 in the fourth, 5 in the fifith... I want to know the probability of getting 5 calls in a period of 10 hours. Can I use Poisson?

Comment: Can you link to where you found that? There is a difference between a Poisson process and a Poisson distribution.

Comment: In your "for instance", you might assume a Poisson distribution (which may or may not be reasonable) for the total number of calls in $10$ hours and estimate the total rate over the $10$ hours perhaps from $10$ times the average rate per hour in your observations.  Seeing an average of $4$ an hour in your observations could suggest a rate of $40$ over $10$ hours and that only seeing $5$ in $10$ hours would be unlikely.

Comment: The book is in Portuguese @Henry, so I don't think it would be useful to you. Basically, the exercise is saying "In a call centre, the number of calls follow a Poisson distribution, with an average of 8 calls per minute. Find the probability that we have 10 or more call in a minute."